# Disable .Net JIT Optimization at process level

Tags: c#, optimization, jit

I know it's possible to disable .Net's JIT Optimizations at the assembly or executable level [by creating an INI file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x.aspx).

**Is it possible to do the same thing for all of the assemblies or executables in a process?**

My specific use case is debugging exception handling in an ASP.Net MVC application running in IIS Express - I've got my `System.Web.Mvc.ini` file set up, and before I write files for each of the other DLLs I think I *may* enter, and which may or may not be loaded from the GAC, I figured I'd ask if a blanket method is available.

Comment: is this for debugging in IIS?

Comment: @Mgetz - IIS Express.  I updated the question as well.

Comment: are you trying to debug your own DLL or a system DLL?

Comment: you can try turning off `Just My Code` in the Visual Studio options, but that's [not guaranteed to work](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4083118-allow-developers-to-step-through-net-framework-so)

Comment: I had to turn off `Just My Code` well before I could get to the point I'm at now.  This question is not about getting *into* the .Net Framework code, it's about running it without JIT compiler optimizations so I can actually **see** what's going on.